# exchanging Unicode char ruins char before this unicode char

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have a big list with unicode char's, which i want to exchange with some ASCII chars with following code (This code does some stuff more):

```
while ($Zeile=<STDIN>)
{
@Zeile=split('\t',$Zeile);
$i=0;
foreach(@Zeile)
    {
    if ($i>1) 
        {
        $entry=$_;
        $entry=~s/\(Details\)/ /;
        $entry=~s/\x{00BC}/.25/;
        $entry=~s/\x{00BD}/.5/;
        $entry=~s/\x{00BE}/.75/; 
        print($entry);
        }
    $i++;
    }
}
```

But in the result there will be inserted a char, which is no unicode char. For example "7½" changes to "7�.5" (Both copied and pasted)

Comment: The very first caveat on the perlunicode page is _"In order to preserve backward compatibility, Perl does not turn on full internal Unicode support unless the pragma use feature 'unicode_strings' is specified. (This is automatically selected if you use use 5.012 or higher.) Failure to do this can trigger unexpected surprises."_  Did you enable either of these pragmas?

Comment: Iserting of 
[code]use feature 'unicode_strings';
use utf8[/code] 
in the first line doesn't change anything :(
[code]use 5.012;[/code] produces an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you never specified that `STDIN` is a utf-8 stream. Something like

```
binmode STDIN, ":utf8";
```

may fix this.